# Active Directory how to get user from distinguishedName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I need some help on retrieving a user with distinguishedName in asp.net mvc project. I have a search function that has 2 properties to load, "displayName" and "distinguishedName". Once I find, I return a view with a list containing these two parameters for each user found. Then I want to be able to click on a user and immediately show their information. So how do I load the information about the user once I only have these two parameters passed through?

Here is the function that initially searches:

```
public List<string> SearchUserByName(string name){
        try{

                DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            resultCollection = search.FindAll();

            if (resultCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(SearchResult sResult in resultCollection)
                {
                    if (sResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].Equals(null) ||
                        sResult.Properties["displayName"][0].Equals(null))
                        continue;

                    displayName.Add(sResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString());
                    displayName.Add(sResult.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString());
                }
            }
            ldapConnection.Close();
            ldapConnection.Dispose();
            search.Dispose();
            return displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Résultat de recherche d'utilisateurs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Résultat de recherche d'utilisateurs</h2>


    @{
        var incLoop = 0;
        var incArr = 0;
        var list = (List<string>)ViewData["Names"];
        var size = list.Count();
        string[] objSID = new string[size];
        foreach (var link in list)
        {
            if (incLoop % 2 == 0)
            {
                objSID[incArr] = link;
                incArr++;
            }
            else
            {
               <a href="@Url.Action("ShowUserInfo", "Home", new {dinstinguishedName=objSID[incArr-1]})">@link</a><br/>

            }
            incLoop++;
        }
    }
</body>
</html>
```

If you click on @link in the  tag, you get the information, which is shown in the next view. I've also split my list to not show the distinguishedName in the search result view.
What I have done for now, is researching the Active Directory when you click on the link, but it seems like bad practice (searching twice for one result). Any ideas?

Thank you, hope it's clear

Comment: You can just append the extra info you need as route values to the Action links.

Comment: Yeah, only problem is that if I show 1K users, it mights be a bit heavy (if I understood you correctly).

Comment: Well if you're going to show 1K users anyway, i dont think that adding a couple of extra route values to the link will make that much difference to the performance of the browser. i recently rendered a tree view with 1000's of folders at once and was fine. But just page your results if its a concern.

Comment: Oh ok, I will try it then thank you :)